# HTTP Basic authentication seems to fail with JAX-WS client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I am making a call to a soap web service, using a jax-ws client generated with cxf-codegen-plugin.

The web service i am calling implements a HTTP basic authentication, so I use the following properties in my request context to fill username/password :

```
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
```

The problem is when the calls are executed no response is received, and no error is logged.
The request is logged but then the http connection seems to remain active while nothing happens. The web services respond correclty with soapUI so the problem is definitly in the client side.

I think the HTTP headers, which are supposed to hold the username/password are not sent properly, because the following line returns null :

```
soapMessageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: SOLVED. The problem was in fact due to the "Transfert-Encoding" http parameter, which was sent with the value "chunked". And apparently with this value the web service server does not respond properly (no error but the http call freezes). However if someone can explain why my http headers are returned as null from the soapMessageContext i would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a soap header for authentication:

http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.fr/2011/01/how-to-add-soap-header-using-jax-ws.html

Comment: It's a HTTP authentication, so it's not about the soap.